# Android Spinner Item selected text

Tags: android

It looks pretty straight forward but it's not working for me. I am trying to get item text from a Spinner when Item is selected.

```
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stnacspinner);
        cspinner = aircraft.getDistinctStation();

       sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {     
            @Override     
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) { 
                Functions.CustomToastShort(getBaseContext(),  sp.getSelectedItem().toString() );
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

It's returning "android.database.sqlite.Sq;LiteCursor@40e06dc0"

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

well you are getting the string representation of the object which is memory address.

```
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stnacspinner); 
        cspinner = aircraft.getDistinctStation(); 

       sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {      
            @Override      
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {  
                Functions.CustomToastShort(getBaseContext(),  sp.getSelectedItem().toString() );
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { 

            } 
        }); 

sp.getSelectedItem().toString() //returns "android.database.sqlite.Sq;LiteCursor@40e06dc0"
```

Comment: @ Mayank, getText() not available in `Spinner` class.

Comment: (String) ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.stnacspinnertext)).getText() ... worked!!

Answer (score 0):

`selectedItemView.getText()`  or  `sp.getSelectedItem().getText()` should do the trick.